# Access iriInfo in called Method

Tags: java, jax-rs, uri

This code works to access the uriInfo:

```
@Path("/testing")
public class Testing {
    @javax.ws.rs.core.Context UriInfo uriInfo;  

@POST
@Path("/test2")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response test2(
  @FormParam("sessionId") String sessionId ) {

  String currentUserId = Utils.setup(sessionId); 

  String accessPath = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toASCIIString();
  System.out.println("The client used this URI to reach this resource method: " + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toASCIIString());

//  Utils.test3("print this"); 
    return Response.ok("Test 2 ended").build();

        }
```

When I try to access the uriInfo in the called method Utils.test3("print this");  Here:

```
public class Utils { 
 @javax.ws.rs.core.Context static UriInfo uriInfo;  

public static String setup(String sessionId) {

  if (!com.retailapppartners.Utils.validSession(sessionId)) {
      throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }

  String currentUserId = com.retailapppartners.Utils.getUserFromSession(sessionId);
  MDC.put("user-id", currentUserId);

  return currentUserId;
  }

public static void test3(String message) {

    System.out.println(message);
    String path = uriInfo.getPath(); 
//      System.out.println("The client used this URI: " + uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toASCIIString());

    return;
```

}

This fails with null pointer exception.  I want to see the path uri in the called method to confirm security for all methods in my utils called method.  I have searched hi and low for called examples of this.  Thanks

Comment: You can't just decide to inject it anywhere you want. Just pass it in as an argument to the method.

Comment: @peeskillet - My App is pretty far along and I wanted to add this security test inside the Utils class (does other security stuff too).  I already call the Utils class about 200 times from other methods.  I would prefer not to have to change all of these existing calls to add the argument.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Like I said, you can't just decide to inject it anywhere you want. The class being injected into needs to be managed by the JAX-RS runtime, as it's the one that will be doing the injecting. A resource class is managed, a filter provider is managed, that's why you can inject into them. You're utility class is not. And in any case, I don't think it would even work for a utility class (even if you were to somehow get it managed) because of the static nature.

Comment: @peeskillet - It seems from your comment I'm headed in the wrong direction to think my utility class will be able to have access to the URI info without passing it as a parameter from each (200+) calling classes.  I was hoping to not have to re-code all of these calls to beef up my security to the URI level.  Any further insight would be great.

Comment: If security is what you're trying to solve, maybe look into using a filter ([`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9509)). The documentation linked is for Jersey, but the filter class (interface) is in the JAX-RS 2 spec. You can inject the `UriInfo` into there. You can inject `ResourceInfo` to get the method or class, to possibly do some reflection for annotations maybe to do some authorization.

Comment: Even your servlet container offers some security feature at the "url level"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing with my comment.. into an answer

> Like I said, you can't just decide to inject it anywhere you want. The class being injected into needs to be managed by the JAX-RS runtime, as it's the one that will be doing the injecting. A resource class is managed, a filter provider is managed, that's why you can inject into them. You're utility class is not. And in any case, I don't think it would even work for a [static] "utility" class (even if you were to somehow get it managed) because of the static nature.

Let me just first mention, that `UriInfo` is specific to each request. `static`, by nature is "global". You cannot inject it as a static field.

One solution I can see is to make the `Utils` class (and methods) non-static, and use the underlying injection framework to inject an instance of the `Utils` class, where ever you need it. This way, if the `Utils` class is managed, then it should be able to inject the managed `UriInfo` instance. How this (getting the `Utils` class managed) will be achieved depends on the implementation you are using, and it's underlying injection framework.

For instance, with Jersey (2), I could do this

```
public class Utils {  
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    public String test(String s) {
        return s + "=" +uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString();
    }
}

@Path("some")
public class SomeResource {  
    @Inject
    Utils utils;

    @GET
    public Response getSomething() {
        return Response.ok(utils.test("Hello")).build();
    }
}

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("stackoverflow.jersey.test");
        register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Utils.class).to(Utils.class);
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

And this works just fine

> `C:\>curl -v http://localhost:8080/some`
>   **Result:** `Hello=http://localhost:8080/some`

Jersey uses HK2 for its injection, so I am able to leverage it to injection of my `Utils` class.

Now this is probably not the answer you're looking for (as it defeats the purpose of a static utility class), but what you are trying too just can't be done. Either way you go, whether refactoring to pass the `UriInfo` to your static methods, or the solution above, you will probably have a lot of refactoring to do. I'm surprised you've already created 200 methods using this functionality, before making sure one worked :/

Comment: Exactly! Thats why i recommended changing to non static method as well as instance variable

Comment: I was forced to recode and pass the Uri as a parameter into my Utils class.  Thanks @peeskillet for the detailed solution above.  FYI - I had built the Utils class earlier for other verification (valid Session UUID)  I was trying to add another layer of security when I ran into this issue.  Had I known about my new requirements I would have coded the 200+ methods better the first time :))  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the @Context annotation to inject an instance of UriInfo into an field variable or method parameter of your resource class

e.g. #1

```
public String find(@Context UriInfo uri){}
```

e.g. #2

```
public class RESTResource{
   @Context
   private UriInfo uri;
}
```

Comment: Is the resource class the "calling" class or the "called" class.  See my comment above.  I'm trying to avoid adding a parameter to every one of my existing calls.  I will update the code above to show my caller using at-Context. `@Path("/testing")
public class Testing {
 @javax.ws.rs.core.Context UriInfo uriInfo; 
`

Comment: Resource class is the one which is called. In your example, its the Testing class. As I said, you can use @Context to inject an UriInfo as an instance variable as well.

Comment: My called methods are  Utils.setup(sessionId) and Utils.test3("print this"); The second one is currently comment out as I get the null pointer exeption. This line `String path = uriInfo.getPath(); ` fails in the test3 method.  I added beginning of Utils class with the @Context code to show how I am using it.

Comment: Remove the static identifier from the uriInfo variable and retry please

Comment: The compiler is making me change the Utils.test3 method non-static.  After I do then the call `Utils.test3("print this")` barks at me: _Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method test3(String) from the type Utils_

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that. Please change the static method as well and see if you still get a NPE

Comment: I did change the method Utils.test3 from static to not and the calling method will not compile due to: _Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method test3(String) from the type Utils_  Is there something i'm missing on the non-static nature of my method now?  My research is not turning up anything obvious to me at least.